# Check if X is in between C and D

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some trouble creating a single formula that checks if:

```
is X in between C and D? Yes/No
```

[image]

- All variables can have different values (but C will always be the same or bigger then C, D will always be bigger then C and E will always be bigger then D)
- B can also be different in each calculation, but its the same length for each span
- A, C, D and E are always known values
- In the picture a B is in between C and D, so the answer would be yes.
- The letters are years and can have any value. An example could be

  A = 1980
  B = 15 years
  C = 2020
  D = 2040
  E = 2055

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just need an expression to evaluate? You can think about this in terms of distance. Is the distance from the midpoint between $C$ and $D$, less than half of the distance between $C$ and $D$? Or,
$$
\left|x- \frac{C+D}{2}\right| < \frac{|D-C|}{2}
$$
This is equivalent to the truth value of $C < x < D$ (assuming $C< D$), but uses only one comparison.

---

Plugging in the values you gave, we get $\frac{|D-C|}{2} = 10$ and $\frac{C+D}{2}\ = 2030$. Now the question is

> Is there an integer $k$ so that
> $$
> |(1980+15k) - 2030| < 10
> $$?

Opening the parentheses, we get
$$
|-50 + 15k| < 10
$$
or
$$
-10 < -50 + 15k < 10
$$
or
$$
40 <  15k < 60
$$
or
$$
\frac{40}{15} < k < \frac{60}{15}
$$
So is there an integer between $\frac{40}{15} \approx 2.857$ and $\frac{60}{15}=4$ ?

Comment: Yes, I just need an expression to evaluate. And yes, D will always be bigger then C. Is that the same as 'if [D minus C] is bigger then B'? In other words: If the length of C-D is bigger then B, there would definetely be an intersection. However, the places of C and D can be very wide (this test would suffice) but also very short. So if the distance between C and D is smaller then B, you still dont know if there will be an intersection with a B-point

Comment: I would not say that it's the same as that. I don't know if $D$ and $C$ have any relationship to $B$. Are you able to use the expression that I wrote? I'm pretty confident that it should work.

Comment: I think in Excel you're formula would be written as '=AND( C < x , x < D)'. But the thing is, I dont know x. All values are known, but not x (however the lenght of B is, and it always starts at A).

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're doing. Isn't $x$ equal to $A+3B$ ?

Comment: Imagine a building (constructed in year 1980, at point A) that has an installation. The installation is replaced every 15 years (B). We need to know if there will be a replacement in between 2020 (C) and 2040 (D). So in this case x equals A + 3B indeed, but any of these numbers are variable (many different kinds of installations, and each building has different construction years and renovation years)

Comment: C and D might as well be 1985 and 1988. In that case there was no replacement. Or C could be A+2B+1 and D could be C+3. How to evaluate if there will be an installation replacement (x) in between?

Comment: Thank you! It took a while to get to the idea of 'integer between' but once we did, we knew this was the missing link. Translating it in Excel and other code to `=ROUNDDOWN((D-A)/B;0)>
ROUNDDOWN((C-A)/B;0)` does the job :)